# 500 error for HTTP server request timeout?

Tags: tomcat, timeout

Normally when a HTTP request to the server gets timed out, server will return "408 Request Timeout" error. Is it possible for server to return the "500 Internal Server" error instead?

I am asking this because I am working on a web application. I know the task for the server takes a very long time to complete, so I am expecting a timeout anyway. When I monitor the AJAX request to the server, the request gets terminated almost exactly after 60 seconds +/- 0.5. This seems very likely to be server timeout. However, I am getting "500 Internal Server" error instead of 408.

It is a Spring application running on Tomcat. I have limited access to the server so I can't see the server log to see what exactly was going on. Could it be the server timeout causing the termination of database connection and hence the 500 error?

P.S. I know 500 error sometimes happens on Apache HTTP Web server for request timeout, but would that happen on Tomcat too?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are passing wrong credentials of DB or wrong command to make the connection with the remote server. check your command as well as your credentials as same thing have recently occurred with me.